# Can I pull ads from facebook pages that are not mine using facebook api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-business-sdk

I want to develop a web application that pulls the ads that the pages are running on.

Those that appear in the ad library.

It is possible? Can I pull ads from pages that are not mine?

If possible, how do I do this? Can I do it with facebook-business-node-sdk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any reference to this in the SDK but seems you could call the [Ads Library API](https://web.facebook.com/ads/library/api/?source=archive-landing-page&_rdc=1&_rdr) by yourself with the following example:

```
const bizSdk = require('facebook-nodejs-business-sdk');

const access_token = '<the_token>';

const api = bizSdk.FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token);
const showDebugingInfo = true; // Setting this to true shows more debugging 
info.
if (showDebugingInfo) {
    api.setDebug(true);
}

const params = {
    search_terms: 'california',
    ad_type: 'POLITICAL_AND_ISSUE_ADS',
    ad_reached_countries: '["US"]',
};

api.call('GET', ['ads_archive'], params).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('something bad happened somewhere', error);
});
```

This code will output something like:

```
{"data":[{"page_id":"111639843986466","ad_snapshot_url":"https://www.facebook.com/ads/archive/render_ad/?id=855669505302615&access_token=EAAN04fZCp9g8BAKCnu2DML2jUH8fh46E4Oz3vKe93A4yeFKhME8zN071d81toxSg8sjRFK2ZAVmv2Mx7lKFY4pLxTzLUYWjCSBE62he832YTYlIZAC5pD9dEVHI6xXR3SFJFtMsZBU3YTs3cgmTycQ2XHUI97WKYfgnyiUM3Vc1f424LbZBirfdczmb1QRDAZD","ad_delivery_start_time":"2021-08-10","id":"855669505302615"},{"page_id":"123450447708791","ad_snapshot_url":"https://www.facebook.com/ads/archive/render_ad/?id=1038603186955396&access_token=EAAN04fZCp9g8BAKCnu2DML2jUH8fh46E4Oz3vKe93A4yeFKhME8zN071d81toxSg8sjRFK2ZAVmv2Mx7lKFY4pLxTzLUYWjCSBE62he832YTYlIZAC5pD9dEVHI6xXR3SFJFtMsZBU3YTs3cgmTycQ2XHUI97WKYfgnyiUM3Vc1f424LbZBirfdczmb1QRDAZD","ad_delivery_start_time":"2021-08-09","id":"1038603186955396"},....
```